# Filtering data from 3 different tables in django with 1 intermediate table

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have four models in my django application with following structure:

```
    class User(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField()
        last_name = models.CharField()

    class Customer(models.Model):
        kyc_record = models.ForeignKey(CustomerKYCRecord, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,default=None)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class SomeItem(models.Model):
        price = models.DecimalField()
        customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class SomeOtherItem(models.Model):
        transaction_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='INITIATED')
        some_item = models.ForeignKey(SomeItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
```

I have to create an API and I have been given a list of `SomeItem`. I have to write a django queryset line to extract `first_name` and `last_name` from `User` model, all details of `SomeItem` model and all details of `SomeOtherItem` model(if present).
I also have to create a serializer to parse the data as a Python dict.

Will be great if one can help me in this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `django queryset line to filter first_name and last_name from User model` Filter it how?

Comment: I have to extract the first and last names for all the matching queries. Sorry for the use of inappropriate word.